# ¿Como seleccionar contenido concreto de un fichero y escribirlo en otro?

Tags: java, poo

Tengo que leer un fichero y, luego seleccionar contenido concreto, escribirlo en otro fichero. El fichero que tengo que leer tiene varias líneas y cada línea tiene este formato: 
    "contenido1","contenido2","contenido3","contenido4","123"

Tengo que seleccionar el contenido `1,2,3` y el índice `5` que es numérico y escribirlo en otro fichero.
He implementado el `bufferedRead()` y `bufferWrite()`, pero no sé como seleccionar el contenido y escribirlo.

Les dejo mi código:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class leerContenido {

    public String leerPaises(String ruta){
        String textoLeido = "";
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ruta));
            String str;
            String temp = "";
            while((str = br.readLine()) !=null){
                temp = temp + str;                
            }

            textoLeido = temp;

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado");
        }

        return textoLeido;

    }

        public void escribir(String ruta){
            leerContenido lc = new leerContenido();
            String str1 = lc.leerPaises("C:\\archivoTXT\\paises_del_mundo.txt");
            String s1= "";
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ruta));
            bw.write(str1);


            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Archivo no escrito");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: ¿el contenido entre comillas es exactamente "contenido1" o puede variar?
Porque se me ocurre que en cada linea que lea, hacer un `str.split(",")` y de ahí obtener del arreglo solo las posiciones 0,1,2 y 4.
La pregunta surge porque si el "contenido1" o cualquiera tiene comas, pues no serviría mi planteamiento.

Comment: No, puede variar. En realidad son paises del mundo y están clasificados de esta forma: "Afganistán","Afghanistan","Afghanistan","AF","AFG","93"   ////          
                 "Albania","Albania","Albanie","AL","ALB","355"

Comment: Entonces sí lo puede realizar de esa manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se podría hacer es un `split(',')` a cada linea que lea en el archivo (teniendo en cuenta que las comas solo se utilizan en el archivo para separar el contenido).
Esa función le devuelve un arreglo con los String obtenidos, y solo accedería a las posiciones de las que desee obtener su valor.

En su caso sería así:

```
public class leerContenido {
    public String leerPaises(String ruta){
        String textoLeido = "";
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ruta));
            String str;
            String temp = "";
            while((str = br.readLine()) !=null){

                String[] contenidos = str.split(","); //arreglo con los contenidos

                for (int i=0;i<= contenidos.length; i++) {//Recorre el arreglo

                    if(i==3) continue; //Saltamos la posición que no queremos obtener, pero seguimos ejecutando el ciclo

                    str+= contenidos[i]; //Concatenamos el "comtenido" en curso
                }
                textoLeido += str;                
            }

            textoLeido = temp;

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado");
        }

        return textoLeido;

    }

    public void escribir(String ruta){
        leerContenido lc = new leerContenido();
        String str1 = lc.leerPaises("C:\\archivoTXT\\paises_del_mundo.txt");
        String s1= "";
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ruta));
            bw.write(str1);


            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Archivo no escrito");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he probado las correcciones que me has hecho pero no me funciona:(. Ahora bien he conseguido hacer funcionar el mío a medias porque me escribe en el fichero el contenido deseado, pero en la siguiente línea, me vuelve a escribir toda la línea sin el split. Si quito la línea bw.write(s); no me escribe nada en el fichero

Answer (score 0):

he probado las correcciones que me has hecho pero no me funciona:(.
Ahora bien he conseguido hacer funcionar el mío a medias porque me escribe en el fichero el contenido deseado, pero en la siguiente línea, me vuelve a escribir toda la línea sin el split. Si quito la línea bw.write(s); no me escribe nada en el fichero, y si la devuelvo, vuelvo al mismo problema.

public class leer {

```
public void read(){
 File f = new File("C:\\archivoTXT\\paises_del_mundo.txt");
 //int x = 105;
 try{
 FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\archivoTXT\\coco.txt"));
 String s;
 do{
 s = br.readLine();
 String[] parts = s.split(",");

        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];
        String part6 = parts[5];

         bw.write(parts[0]); 
         bw.write(parts[1]);            
         bw.write(parts[5]);

         bw.newLine();


 bw.write(s);
 System.out.println(s);
 }while(s!=null);
 bw.close();

 }catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado");
 }
```

}

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Me faltaba el Flush();

Answer (score 0):

si lo que queires es copiar lineas especificas o desde una posicion especifica el contenido de un archivo a otro te recomiendo utilizar

> RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(ruta,"rw");

para obtener la posicion desde donde quiero copiar a otro archivo lo haria asi:

> long puntero= raf.getFilePointer();

y para ubicarme en esa posicion seria:

> raf.seek(puntero);

y podrias usar el bufferwriter para escribir en el nuevoi fichero el contenido